# Wordpress jQuery menu development

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

I'm pretty new to jquery in wordpress. I have managed to blend in the submenu when my mouse is over a first-level element of the menu.

```
$('li.menu-item').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children().fadeIn();
});
```

When the user leaves the 2nd level elements of the menu it disappears like it should.

```
$('li.menu-item > ul').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

My problem is now, that when I move the mouse from one first-level element to the next both 2nd-level menus are shown. 
I tried

```
$('li.menu-item').mouseleave(function() {
    // $(this).children().fadeOut();
});
```

But with that the 1st-level element disappears as well.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle by copying your JS code and the rendered HTML from your Browser in the page you're referring to.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your reply. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghostflasher/fYcQ8/10/)